# Pyinstaller: 'ocrmypdf" distribution was not found

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am currently working on a program to OCR a PDF and extract the tables from it using tabula-py. Everything works great using the .py file on my own PC, but when I try to launch it as an executable using PyInstaller, I get this error:

```
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'ocrmypdf' distribution was not found and is required by the application
[10988] Failed to execute script ocr
```

An .exe is necessary since I will need to distribute this program to users that will not have Python nor the ocrmypdf dependencies installed (Tesseract and Ghostscript). I am fairly new to Python overall, how can I fix this issue?

Thanks!