# python -> ocrmypdf package to convert as executable

Tags: python, python-3.6

I want to convert the entire ocrmypdf pkg to exe
so, i navigated to ocrmypdf folder & opened CMD
Commands used

1. pyinstaller --openfile main.py
2. auto-py-to-exe
   am not getting the .exe file

[image]

the same error repeats on auto-py-to-exe too.

Comment: Did you install the `PIPE` package, the error says you don't have it.  for virtual environment -> `pip install pipe`. For conda environment -> `conda install -c auto pipe`

Comment: Yes added PIPE & For conda 
 Error : Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement menuinst (from conda) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for menuinst (from conda)

Comment: someone posted the error what i got ! the same issue am facing here !
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61746252/pyinstaller-ocrmypdf-distribution-was-not-found